# How to select latest value for each day in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this:

[image]

How do i find latest value of each day in oracle with sql?

I try:

```
select max(datetime), amount
from ORDER_ITEMS
group by datetime, amount
```

But it does not give a right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function such as

```sql
SELECT datetime, amount
  FROM 
  ( SELECT datetime,
           amount,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TRUNC(datetime) ORDER BY datetime DESC) AS rn
      FROM order_items)
 WHERE rn = 1
```

if there might occur ties for `datetime` values, then prefer using `DENSE_RANK()` function instead as

```sql
SELECT datetime, amount
  FROM 
  ( SELECT datetime,
           amount,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY TRUNC(datetime) ORDER BY datetime DESC) AS dr
      FROM order_items)
 WHERE dr = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. How do i find the earliest amount for each day?

Comment: you're welcome @bibiji, just remove the DESC after datetime column within the ORDER BY clause in order to determine the earliest data [such as](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=64e697248c145b15ad6daf187904551e)